# «Крутится» или «крутятся»?

Tags: грамматика, согласование, сказуемые

*Вокруг меня всегда крут**и**тся много друзей.*
Или:
*Вокруг меня всегда крут**я**тся много друзей.*

Как правильно написать? И какое правило использовать в этом случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Какое правило**

§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

**Общие положения:**

(1) Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на **совместное** действие, форма множественного числа – на **раздельное** совершение действия.

(2) Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на **совокупность** предметов, форма множественного числа – на **отдельные** предметы.

(3) Также: пункт 12.  При наличии в составе подлежащего слов ***много, мало, немного, немало, сколько, столько*** преобладает форма единственного числа сказуемого, однако в последнее время, в связи с общей тенденцией к согласованию по смыслу, форма множественного числа находит все более широкое распространение. Например:

а) И много других подобных дум **проходило** в уме моем... (Лермонтов); Сколько еще сказок и воспоминаний **осталось** в ее памяти! (Горький);

б)      Много совершенно недетских впечатлений **стали** для меня как-то страшно доступны (Достоевский);

**2. Что выберем**

Выбираем согласование в ед. числе: *Вокруг меня всегда **крутится много друзей**.*

**Пояснение**

(1) Кроме формального решения, указанного у Розенталя в п. 12, здесь можно применить правило **совокупного действия лиц**. Хотя они могут меняться, но впечатление остаётся постоянным – их много.

(2) Кроме того,  сказуемое находится **рядом** с подлежащим, поэтому **сочетаемость по форме очень важна.** Если посмотреть приведенные примеры, то форма мн. числа используется для сказуемых, где нет прямого контакта с подлежащим.